# using Leaflet.Label with GeoJSON points

Tags: leaflet

There are numerous references to [leaflet.label](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label) working fine with GeoJSON points, but I've yet to find one example.
Here's what i've tried so far:

```
//Add labels layer
var labelStyle = {
    color: '#CCC',
    opacity: 1
};

var labelMarkerOptions = {
        opacity: 0,
        fillOpacity: 0
};

var labelLayer = L.geoJson(labels, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.Marker(latlng, labelMarkerOptions);
        },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindLabel(feature.properties.Name, {noHide:true});
        }
});
labelLayer.eachLayer(function(l) {l.showLabel();});
map.addLayer(labelLayer);
layerControl.addOverlay(labelLayer, 'Site Labels');
```

This adds a layer of my points, but with the default larkers, and no labels.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show only the label, return `L.circleMarker` instead of `L.Marker`:

```
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, labelMarkerOptions);
},
```

If you need `L.Marker` for some other reason, bind the label directly to marker:

```
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.Marker(latlng, labelMarkerOptions).bindLabel(feature.properties.Name, {noHide:true});
},
```